# Is the solveability of a diophantine equation in two variables decideable?

Tags: reference-request, diophantine-equations, decidability

Here :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem

it is stated that Hilbert's tenth problem is already undecideable, if we allow $9$ unknowns.

I wonder whether the case of two variables is known :

> Is the solveability of a diophantine equation in two unknowns decideable ?

For degree $1$, this is clearly true (even for arbitary many unknowns) and for $2$, if I am informed right, this is always the case. Is it known whether it is decideable in general ? And if not, is it known for which degree it is undecideable ?